# How to post from my Api a GeoPoint with firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

Im novice in coding and Im actually making my first Api.

My problem is that I try to post some Geopoint in my firestore database but it looks impossible this is my code below :

```
const db = admin.firestore();
const pointGps = new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(Number, Number);

app.post('/api/createrdv', (req, res) => {
    (async () => {
        try {
            await db.collection('rvlist').doc() // CREATION AUTO DE L'ID // POUR CREER AVEC ID PERSO ('/' + req.body.id + '/')
                .create({

                  //id: req.body.id,
                    latlong: pointGps({lat: req.body.lat, lng: req.body.lng}),
                    name: req.body.name,
                    phone: req.body.phone,
                    psnumber: req.body.psnumber,
                    rvtime: req.body.rvtime,
                    vu: req.body.vu

                });

            return res.status(200).send();

        } catch (error) {

            console.log(error);
            return res.status(500).send(error);
        }
    })();
});
```

Error: Value for argument "latitude" is not a valid number.

same problem I cannot use the database for any timestamp.

Any Idea for how to do it or is this at least possible with firestore ? Im stuck since two days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const db = admin.firestore();


app.post('/api/createrdv', (req, res) => {
    (async () => {
        try {
            await db.collection('rvlist').doc() // CREATION AUTO DE L'ID // POUR CREER AVEC ID PERSO ('/' + req.body.id + '/')
            .create({

                  //id: req.body.id,
                    latlong: new GeoPoint(Number(req.body.lat), 
                                          Number(req.body.lng)),
                    name: req.body.name,
                    phone: req.body.phone,
                    psnumber: req.body.psnumber,
                    rvtime: req.body.rvtime,
                    vu: req.body.vu

                });

            return res.status(200).send();

        } catch (error) {

            console.log(error);
            return res.status(500).send(error);
        }
    })();
});
```

Comment: +1 GG ! my hero haha so i use your idea and use this line it works perfectly I can post coordonate straight in the firestore database                                          latlong: new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(Number(req.body.lat),
                                                        Number(req.body.lng)),

Answer (score 0):

If you need the answer thanks to tobzilla

```
app.post('/api/create', (req, res) => {
(async () => {
    try {
        await db.collection('psdata').doc() // CREATION DE L'ID AUTOMATIQUE // POUR CREER AVEC ID PERSO ('/' + req.body.id + '/') //
            .create({

              //id: req.body.id,
                latlong: new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(Number(req.body.lat),
                                                      Number(req.body.lng)),
                city: req.body.city,
                name: req.body.name,
                phone: req.body.phone,
                psnumber: req.body.psnumber,
                speciality: req.body.speciality,
                streetadress: req.body.streetadress,
                zipcode: req.body.zipcode,
                

            });

        return res.status(200).send();
```